# iOS ATS: Is this error because of the App or the server?

Tags: ios, runtime-error, secure-transport

I am getting the following error from my App.

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

I know this is more than likely because of my server not having the recommend security that Apple wants. However, I want to make sure before asking for my web developer to update the security in the backend?

I checked the secure transport class which can be viewed here http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_ssl/libsecurity_ssl-36800/lib/SecureTransport.h.

and it says you will get error code -9802 because of a Fatal alert. That is pretty vague to be honest with you. I will give my web developer the official check list by Apple if this isn't my fault. Is this error caused by me or the backend security not being up to date with Apple's recommendation?

Edit : This seems like an ATS issue.
When I add NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in the info plist and set NSAllowsArbitaryLoads to YES the issue doesn't show up anymore.

Comment: If ATS has a problem it will show you in the console

Comment: What I meant is that if ATS is the thing that it issuing the message it will say "application transport security" in the console mesage

Comment: It doesn't say that for me in the console, but it should be ATS because if I add NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in the info plist and set NSAllowsArbitaryLoads to YES the issue doesn't show up anymore.